# Naming of include/exclude enum

Tags: language-agnostic, enums, naming-conventions

I'm having difficulties naming an enum that should have the values `Include` and `Exclude`. If the enumerations were `In` and `Out`, I'd name the enum `Direction`, but what's the similar and appropriate word to group `Include` and `Exclude`?

The context and application of the enum is to set whether a selection of objects are to be included in or excluded from a larger set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "Inclusion"?

Comment: I'm not perfectly happy that there's no "direction" for include/exclude, but "Inclusion" is close enough.

Answer (score 2):

`Filter` maybe? Or `Condition`?

Comment: Not bad suggestions, but I would rather describe the group (with a property set to `Include` or `Exclude`) itself as a Filter, and not the property describing how the filtering is applied.

Comment: `FilterMethod` then? Or `FilterCondition` :-)

Answer (score 1):

That would really depend on the context I guess, it hard to give a single name to such vague concepts.

Integration ? Integration(Rule|Policy) ?  Yeah, not convincing I know.

Comment: Thanks; I've added a description of the context.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be related to Sets and Subsets. I would say something like SetRelation. If you're talking about Set elements, then maybe you should use Element (BelongsTo|DoesNotBelongTo)

Answer (score 0):

SelectionUsage or SelectionUsageType

Answer (score 0):

T(Filter)Operation = (foInclude, foExclude)